# Can we Wonder Trading pokemon between generations?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

For example, I'm wonder trading some pokemon from Sun & Moon, and in the same time my friend also wonder trading, but he wonder trading from pokemon X & Y.

Is it possible that our trade meet each other in wonder trading?

I've read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291862/which-pok%C3%A9mon-games-can-i-use-to-trade-pok%C3%A9mon-with-the-sun-and-moon-versions) but, I don't think it is also true with Wonder Trading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You may use Pokebank from next month to transfer between generations like in the link you posted, but XYORAS wonder trade is separate from SM's.

[Here's a source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74443717)